# C++: how does the destructor work internally and who calls the default destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor

```
class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
       std::cout << "I am ctor\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
       std::cout << "I am dtor\n";
    }
    void printme()
    {
       std::cout << "I am printme\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
   A aobj;
   aobj.printme();
   aobj.~A();
   aobj.printme();
   return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
$./testdtor
I am ctor
I am printme
I am dtor
I am printme
I am dtor
```

An explicit call to destructor behaves like a normal function call and once the object goes out of scope, the destructor is called, but I would like to know by which entity?

Comment: What do you mean, "entity"? It's called by code generated by the compiler, at the end of the object's scope.

Comment: What makes you think an "entity" calls the destructor? It's just part of the generated code.

Comment: I guess with "entity" OP meant to use a very abstract word, not that he thought such an "entity" is part of his program code or such... He meant "entity" to be abstract enough to include the generated assembly ;)

Comment: @MikeSeymour The garbage collection in Java is done at the discretion of JVM when an explicit call to System.gc() is made; this is what made me think of an "entity" calling the destructor. Tried the same in Perl with an explicit call to DESTROY() and it behaves the same as in C++.

Answer (score 6):

Compiler generates destructor invocation code for all automatic objects. Such destructors are invoked in the order opposite to the object construction order.

The `delete` operator calls object destructor for the object residing at the address pointed to by the operator argument and is normally (I would say *always*) used with the dynamic objects.

This behavior allows reliable memory management and many other useful tricks we love so much in `C++`.

The only situation where you may and in most cases would call destructor manually is when allocating an object using [placement `new`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html) operator.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, I would use "automatic" and "dynamic" instead of "stack" and "heap".

Answer (score 6):

It depends on where the object is, and what it's lifetime is.

- For automatic variables like your example, by code generated at the end of its scope
- For static variables, by code called by the `atexit` mechanism after `main` ends
- For thread-local variables, by a similar mechanism after the thread ends
- For non-static class member variables or base sub-objects, by code generated in the destructor of the class containing it
- For objects created by `new`, by code generated by the corresponding delete-expression
- For objects created by placement-new, the destructor can only be called explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Internally destructor is a usual function. It is used to free resources used by a class and it can have any behaviour.

Calls to destructors are generated by compiler. It called when:

1 Object goes out of scope

```
void foo() {
    // Declare an instance of some object
    MyClass object;

    // code

    // destructor for 'object' called here
}
```

2 When you delete an object: delete myPtr

3 When you delete an array of objects: delete[] myArray

4 If exception is thrown destructors are called for all objects in the scope

There is a case when destructor will not be called. If and exception is thrown during execution object's constructor and escapes it without being catched, destructor for this this object will not be called.

Comment: 4 is a special case of 1 and 3 implies 2 for each element, so I'd wrap them together and call 1+4 the end of lifetime of objects in automatic storage, and 2+3 the end of lifetime of objects from dynamic allocation (usually).